# Display the output of an exec task in ant

Tags: ant, scp

I am scping files using the [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) Ant task. It is working fine, but the output of the scp command is not displayed.

Below is the code

```
  <target name="scp-jar" depends = "jar">
      <exec executable="/usr/bin/scp">
          <arg value="my.jar"/>
          <arg value="myserver:dir"/>          
      </exec>
  </target>
```

What changes I have to make to display the file progress output of the scp command?

Comment: scp won't output the progress bar if stdout isn't a tty, so ant can also not redirect it.. http://cwshep.blogspot.jp/2009/06/showing-scp-progress-using-zenity.html

Comment: @TanukiSoftware Hmm that explains it. So the problem lies with scp, not ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tanuki Software mentioned, `scp` wouldn't print the progress bar if [stdout isn't tty](http://cwshep.blogspot.jp/2009/06/showing-scp-progress-using-zenity.html).

So the problem was more with `scp` and not with the Ant task.

I tried using the `-v` option of `scp`, but it is displaying debugging information and the progress bar.

So there are only two options

- Use Exec task and miss out the progress bar. (or)
- Use Scp task, but it requires extra jar, doesn't work properly in mac and very difficult to make it use the default settings from .sshconfig file.

I ended up choosing the first option.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the output of the command gets written to the stdout and you can specify an output attribute to change it to a file. More details here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

It is difficult to redirect SCP's output though. You might probably want to use the flag -v in your case.

Comment: I have already checked the manual. It says by default the output is re-directed, but it is not happening in this case. You mean the -v flag of the scp command?

Answer (score 0):

The [ant SCP task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) can show that information.  User verbose flag.

This task require [additional jars](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) ( jsch.jar 0.1.42 or later)

Comment: I am not using the scp task because it requires additional jar. I tried setting it up my mac, but couldn't. That's why I ended up using the exec task.

Comment: extending jar by additional jars is good idea. why re-invent the wheel?